Parsing List of Either Type
I'm writing a parser for logic formulae, and it's failing to parse a list of type Either.
The parser works for all cases, except substitution of functions into predicates --
Parsing P(f(x:X)=a:A,b:B) (with parsePredSub) should return the substitution ((f,([(x,X)],A),(a,A)) and the predicate (P, [(a,A),(b,B)]), but instead it only returns (P, [Left b:B]).
Yet parsing f(x:X)=a:A,b:B (with (commaSep ParseVSub)) returns [Right (f(x:X),a:A),Left b:B], which is correct. Somehow the "rights" are getting dropped when I try to wrap this in "pparens".
It's probably a simple issue with combinator syntax. All thoughts appreciated. Thanks.
-- (types Pre and Var and Srt and Sym are String)
type VarSrt = (Var,Srt)
type Ctx = [VarSrt]
type Trm = (Sym,([VarSrt],Srt))
type Sub = (Trm,VarSrt)
type Bind = [Sub]
type Pred = (Pre, Ctx)
type PredSub = (Bind, Pred)

parseVS :: Parser VarSrt
parseVS = do {v<-identifier; string ":"; s<-identifier; return $ (v,s)}

pparens :: Parser a -> Parser (String,a)
pparens par = try $ do {p<-identifier; string "("; z <- par; string ")";
                        return (p,z)}

parseSub :: Parser Sub
parseSub =
  do {(f,a) <- pparens (commaSep parseVS); string "="; spaces;
       (x,s) <- parseVS; spaces;
       return $ ((f,(a,s)),(x,s))}

parseVSub :: Parser VSub
parseVSub = choice [Left <$> try parseVS, Right <$> try parseSub]

------- THE ISSUE --------
parsePredSub :: Parser PredSub
parsePredSub = try $ do {(p,bc) <- pparens (commaSep parseVSub);
                         return (rights bc,(p,lefts bc))}
--------------------------

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = p <* whitespace

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = lexeme ((:) <$> firstChar <*> many nonFirstChar)
  where
    firstChar = letter <|> char '_'
    nonFirstChar = digit <|> firstChar

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol s = try $ lexeme $ do
    u <- many1 (oneOf "<>=+-^%/*!|,")
    guard (s == u)
    return s


You would make the question a lot more approachable by removing the elements that don't pertain to your problem. For example, the clauses with Exists and Forall do not occur in your example string, so could just be removed. Additionally, include all definitions that are relevant. Is identifier defined elsewhere? Imported? What is the specific parser you think should parse the example input(s)? It's impossible to answer the question without knowing such things.

Yes; you're right. I just simplified, and added the definition of identifier. Thanks.

Too much context. It is obviously redundant, since your problem is not in your domain, but in text parsing. Therefore, you will be able to get more help if you formulate the problem in the context of text parsing.

If I am understanding correctly, the test case:
parseTest parsePredSub "P(f(x:X)=a:A,b:B)"

returns:
([(("f",([("x","X")],"A")),("a","A"))],("P",[("b","B")]))

but you instead want it to return
([(("f",([("x","X")],"A")),("a","A"))],("P",[("a","A"),("b","B")]))
                           ^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^

so that the "rights" both contribute a binding and an argument to the predicate.
If so, the "problem" is that your code:
parsePredSub :: Parser PredSub
parsePredSub = try $ do {(p,bc) <- pparens (commaSep parseVSub);
                         return (rights bc,(p,lefts bc))}

splits up the rights (the bindings) and the lefts (the unbound arguments) and only returns the list of unbound arguments as part of the Pred.  You'll need to write a helper function that extracts the VarSrt from both bindings and unbound arguments:
varSrt (Left vs) = vs
varSrt (Right (_,vs)) = vs

and use map varSrt in place of your lefts call to extract all of the VarSrts from both lefts and rights, in order.  Something like this:
parsePredSub :: Parser PredSub
parsePredSub = try $ do {(p,bc) <- pparens (commaSep parseVSub);
                         return (rights bc,(p,map varSrt bc))}
  where varSrt (Left vs) = vs
        varSrt (Right (_,vs)) = vs

Here is a full runnable example illustrating the change:
module EitherParser where

import Control.Monad
import Data.Either
import Text.Parsec

type Parser = Parsec String ()

type Pre = String
type Var = String
type Srt = String
type Sym = String
type VSub = Either VarSrt Sub

commaSep :: Parser a -> Parser [a]
commaSep p = (:) <$> p <*> many (char ',' *> p)

whitespace :: Parser ()
whitespace = spaces

--
-- Your code starts here
--

-- (types Pre and Var and Srt and Sym are String)
type VarSrt = (Var,Srt)
type Ctx = [VarSrt]
type Trm = (Sym,([VarSrt],Srt))
type Sub = (Trm,VarSrt)
type Bind = [Sub]
type Pred = (Pre, Ctx)
type PredSub = (Bind, Pred)

parseVS :: Parser VarSrt
parseVS = do {v<-identifier; string ":"; s<-identifier; return $ (v,s)}

pparens :: Parser a -> Parser (String,a)
pparens par = try $ do {p<-identifier; string "("; z <- par; string ")";
                        return (p,z)}

parseSub :: Parser Sub
parseSub =
  do {(f,a) <- pparens (commaSep parseVS); string "="; spaces;
       (x,s) <- parseVS; spaces;
       return $ ((f,(a,s)),(x,s))}

parseVSub :: Parser VSub
parseVSub = choice [Left <$> try parseVS, Right <$> try parseSub]

------- FIXED VERSION ----
parsePredSub :: Parser PredSub
parsePredSub = try $ do {(p,bc) <- pparens (commaSep parseVSub);
                         return (rights bc,(p,map varSrt bc))}
  where varSrt (Left vs) = vs
        varSrt (Right (_,vs)) = vs
--------------------------

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = p <* whitespace

identifier :: Parser String
identifier = lexeme ((:) <$> firstChar <*> many nonFirstChar)
  where
    firstChar = letter <|> char '_'
    nonFirstChar = digit <|> firstChar

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol s = try $ lexeme $ do
    u <- many1 (oneOf "<>=+-^%/*!|,")
    guard (s == u)
    return s

--
-- Your code ends here
--

main = parseTest parsePredSub "P(f(x:X)=a:A,b:B)"


Ah, this makes perfect sense. It all works. Thank you so much!
